# Enforce running profile form parent POM in pom.xml

Tags: maven

I have about 30 projects and 6 of them must have special (but the same) build process. All of those projects inherit from single parent.
I have defined the special build process in parent. It includes several plugins and lots of configuration.

The inheritance structore is like this:

```
- global-parent (this is the place where special profile is defined)
   -a-parent
      -a-ear
      -a-war
      -a-ejb
      -a-special <--
   -b-parent
      -b-ear
      -b-war
      -b-ejb
      -b-special <--
   -c-parent
      -c-ear
      -c-war
      -c-ejb
      -c-special <--
  etc...
```

So I cannot make those special projects inherit another pom.

How to set "a flag" in those special projects in pom.xml to run **always** against `special-profile`?

For now I've set profile/activation/file/extsts and creates special empty marker file in each special project but this is so ugly. 
I've also tried to use maven-properties-plugin to set some system property flag but it is still ugly.

There must be a more legant way. Is this a bad design?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of doing this is with two levels of parent projects.  I've done this with a "global-parent" and a "webapps-parent" with common configuration / profiles just for the webapp components. However, I observe that you need something like "multiple inheritance" which doesn't quite exist in Maven.

Otherwise, the "file exists" activation is acceptable, in my opinion.

**Addendum**

Without knowing what's exactly "special" about the special modules, it's hard to answer the somewhat subjective question "is this bad design?"

Perhaps a custom plugin that encapsulates all the other plugins would be "better" or "more Maven-ish" but at the end of the day - is your build maintainable and easy to run (i.e. `svn co project; cd project; mvn package`)?

If so, you've achieved your goals.

Comment: I would say that "file exists" is probably less "Maven" than activating based on a property. But I agree with the two levels of parents.

Comment: Multiple inheritance woud be the way. Another way would be some kind of plugins grouping into a single "somethinl-like-a-plugin-execution". Something like a macro or something that work similar to "import" dependency but for plugins.